# One-Loop Yukawa RGEs

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm currently trying to understand how one can write the one-loop RGEs for the Yukawa couplings using the [general formula](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01547677):

[image]

One example I'm interested in is how the author derives, using this formula and starting with the [Yuakwa Lagrangian in Eq. 4.1 the RGEs in Eq. 4.2 and Eq. 4.3](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/671/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01547677.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2FBF01547677&token2=exp=1450606469~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F671%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252FBF01547677.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252FBF01547677*~hmac=8a6053ac594a2ddd481362dae76ba9fc614782dd724be3951f02e3e2584d38a7).

[Another example, starting with](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0206118):

"Between the grand unification scale and the intermediate
 scale, the effective Yukawa interactions are given by
\begin{equation}
 -{\mathcal L}_{Y} =\sum_{i,j}\left( Y^{(10)}_{F\,ij}F_L^{iT}\Phi F_R^{j}
  +Y^{(126)}_{F\,ij}F_L^{iT}\Sigma F_R^{j}
+Y^{(126)}_{R\,ij}F_R^{iT}\overline{\Delta_R} F_R^{j}+h.c.\right),
\end{equation}
where $F_L$ and $F_R$ denote $\bf{(2,1,4)}$ and 
$\bf{(1,2,{\overline{4}})}$ in $\Psi^{i}$, under $G_{224} \equiv SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R \times SU(4)_C$,
 respectively. And also, $\Phi$, $\Sigma$ and $\overline{\Delta_R}$ 
correspond 
to $\bf{(2, 2, 1)}$ in $H$, $\bf{(2, 2, 15)}$ and $\bf{(1, 3, \overline{10})}$ 
in $\overline{\Delta}$, respectively."

How can I derive that:

"...the one loop RGEs for the effective Yukawa couplings first at 
the energy region between the grand 
unification scale and the intermediate sale are given by :
\begin{eqnarray}
16\pi^2\frac{dY^{(10)}_F}{dt}&=&\left(Y^{(10)}_FY^{(10)\dagger}_F
+\frac{15}{4}Y^{(126)}_FY^{(126)\dagger}_F\right)Y^{(10)}_F \nonumber\\
&+&Y^{(10)}_F\left\{Y^{(10)}_FY^{(10)\dagger}_F
+\frac{15}{4}\left(Y^{(126)}_F Y^{(126)\dagger}_F
+Y^{(126)}_R Y^{(126)\dagger}_R \right)\right\} \nonumber\\
&+&4{\mathrm{tr}}\left(Y^{(10)}_F Y^{(10)\dagger}_F\right)Y^{(10)}_F
+\left(\frac{9}{4}g_{2L}^{2}+\frac{9}{4}g_{2R}^{2}
+\frac{15}{4}g_{4C}^{\,2}\right) Y^{(10)}_F,\\
16\pi^2\frac{dY^{(126)}_F}{dt}&=&\left(Y^{(10)}_FY^{(10)\dagger}_F
+\frac{15}{4}Y^{(126)}_FY^{(126)\dagger}_F\right)Y^{(126)}_F \nonumber\\
&+&Y^{(126)}_F\left\{Y^{(10)}_FY^{(10)\dagger}_F
+\frac{15}{4}\left(Y^{(126)}_FY^{(126)\dagger}_F
+Y^{(126)}_R Y^{(126)\dagger}_R \right)\right\} \nonumber\\
&+&{\mathrm{tr}}\left(Y^{(126)}_FY^{(126)\dagger}_F\right)Y^{(126)}_F
+\left(\frac{9}{4}g_{2L}^{2}+\frac{9}{4}g_{2R}^{2}
+\frac{15}{4}g_{4C}^{2}\right) Y^{(126)}_F,\\
16\pi^2\frac{dY^{(126)}_R}{dt}&=&\left\{Y^{(10)}_FY^{(10)\dagger}_F
+\frac{15}{4}\left(Y^{(126)}_FY^{(126)\dagger}_F
+Y^{(126)}_R Y^{(126)\dagger}_R \right)\right\}Y^{(126)}_R \nonumber\\
&+&Y^{(126)}_R\left\{Y^{(10)}_FY^{(10)\dagger}_F
+\frac{15}{4}\left(Y^{(126)}_FY^{(126)\dagger}_F
+Y^{(126)}_R Y^{(126)\dagger}_R \right)\right\} \nonumber\\
&+&{\mathrm{tr}}\left(Y^{(126)}_RY^{(126)\dagger}_R\right)Y^{(126)}_R
+\left(\frac{9}{2}g_{2R}^{2}
+\frac{15}{4}g_{4C}^{2}\right) Y^{(126)}_R,
\end{eqnarray}
where $g_{2L}$, $g_{2R}$ and $g_{4C}$ are the $SU(2)_L$
, $SU(2)_R$ and $SU(4)_C$ 
gauge coupling constants, respectively."  ([Eq. 24-26](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/020611))

- Especially, where does the factor $\frac{15}{4}$ in front of $Y^{(126)}_FY^{(126)\dagger}_F$ etc. come from?
- Why is there no term $Y^{(126)}_R Y^{(126)\dagger}_R Y^{(10)}_F$? Or formulated differently, why is there in the first bracket of the $ Y^{(10)}$ RGE in the first bracket only a term $Y^{(126)}_FY^{(126)\dagger}_F$, but no $Y^{(126)}_R Y^{(126)\dagger}_R$ term?

By using the formula 2.2 "naivly" I would end up with such a term, too and in addition no numerical factors as $\frac{15}{4}$.

**Any ideas or references would be much appreciated!**

(The original reference for the general formula is T.P. Cheng, E. Eichten, and L.-F. Li, Phys. Rev. D9 (1974) 2259)

Comment: Have you tried the programme SARAH? You could verif (or not) the RGEs to two-loop pretty quickly. Of course, it wouldn't give you the same insight.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked for the papers of Machacek and Vaughn (which I suppose is the reference [26] cited in the book you referenced here)? Those papers clarify how to construct/use the RGEs. Nevertheless I will try to help you as well.

- Although I won't deal with it, since it seems to be very particular, I will suppose you are assuming unification under that group where you have your left right symmetry in order to give rise to $SU(2) \times U(1)$ plus global symmetries. However, the first thing is to clarify each one of the real degrees of freedom of the scalars in your model. For instance, the Higgs doublet in the SM has 4 real degrees of freedom. The same you need to do with your $\overline{\Delta}$, $\Sigma$ and $\Phi$.
- In order to obtain the RGEs of the SM, for instance, you will need to label the Yukawas by following a numeration for the scalar real degrees of freedom, regardless the numeration you used (this is absolutely up to you). Do not forget normalization factors $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ when defining the scalar fields. Each Yukawa matrix labeled by the index $a$ (which you choose how to numerate in the previous step) is not the Yukawa matrix that came with the Lagrangian, but is a matrix labeled by the real degree of freedom and more importantly...
- ... whose internal indices are labeling **every fermion field in the theory**. I don't know whether you fields $F$ are going to give rise to SM fermions (as it seems to be anyways), however, you will need to separate each internal degree of freedom therein, i.e. your electron field, your muon field (although the leptons will contribute in the same way, and the same for the quarks), your extra leptons, quarks also, etc. Those will label the internal indices for each $Y^a$ matrix (the $i,j$ indices). At least in the SM there is no problem in putting another matrix as an entry for the whole Yukawa matrix you are building, since the leptonic Yukawa matrix (not the $Y^a$) has the same structure for each flavor.
- Once done this you are almost finishing, since the $a$ indices are labeling the real scalar d.o.f. you got in your theory, so now you need to put these Yukawa matrices in the formula, and, believe me, magically the factor 15/4 should appear (when I did calculations in my case, I got factors of 3/2, 9/2, 21/3 etc after summing the contractions with the $b$ index, although it was for another theory). That 'magic' comes from the contractions of the Yukawa matrices as a whole, and traces, etc and it is not clear at a first sight where these might come from. I strongly recommend to do this in mathematica/maple/maxima or whichever suite for algebraic calculations you like because, although many of the terms inside the $Y^a$ matrices are zero, it can be a tough work to do anyways.
- Notice that this has a lot to do with the gauge numbers of your theory, you need to have clear which are the quantum numbers of your particles under your gauge group, i.e. more involved numbers as Dynkyn indices and Casimirs for each gauge group involved in the underlying symmetry you are using. There is where the factors involving gauge couplings appear.

  I hope to have helped you, and if I am wrong, please, let me know so we both can learn about this ;-).
  Cheers!!!